# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation not fire in 4.3

Tags: ios

In my iPad app, I hava a UIScrollView.
When I run it under "iPad 5 simulator" ,shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation fires and every thing is all right ,But in "iPad 4.3 simulator" ,this event  doesn't fire.

How should I solve this issue?

Another problem :when I test my app in "iPad 5 simulator" this event fires 7 times on launch

Here is part of my Code:

#import "AppDelegate.h"

```
#import "ContentController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window, contentController;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
   {
    NSString *nibTitle = @"iPad";
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    { nibTitle = @"Iphone";
    }
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibTitle owner:self options:nil];

    [self.window addSubview:self.contentController.view];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }

@end
```

contentController.h

@interface ContentController : UIViewController

```
{
    NSArray *contentList;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *contentList;

@end
```

PadContentController.h

```
@interface PadContentController : ContentController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
        {   
        UIScrollView *appScrollView;
        NSMutableArray *viewControllers;
        }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *AppScrollView;


    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *viewControllers;


    @end
```

shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is in PadContentController.

```
   -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
            {
                [super shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
                switch (interfaceOrientation)
                {

                    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
                    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
                      return NO;

                    default:
                        return YES;
                }
            }
```

I have added some views to UIScrollView , shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation  is also implemented in each of these views .
When I run app in "iPad 5 simulator" , shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in PadContentController and in all views are called.
But when I run it in "in iPad 4.3 simulator" just shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in first view is called (just on launch) and shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in  PadContentController doesn't call,as a result rotation does not occur.

Comment: We can't really you with such information. Where is your "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation"? not in your UIScrollView I hope. Is it the parent view controller ? How do you set the parent view controller to the window? (meaning setRootViewController or keyWindow addSubview?), etc.

Comment: Thanks @Vinzius, I added more information.